# No performance increase with Alpha-Beta pruning in Minimax algorithm

Tags: javascript, performance, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am trying to implement alpha-beta pruning into my chess engine, but there are no performance differences, what could I be doing wrong? I tried console logging how many times the algorithm cuts a branch, but it was in the order of hundreds so it prunes the search tree correctly. Even with that the algorithm dosen't have a noticeable performance improvement.

Board evaluation takes about 80ms on average. With alpha-beta pruning the minimax/alpha beta algorithm takes 1.8 seconds looking at depth 3, and without minimax/alpha-beta takes 1.5 seconds.

Here is the code:

```
const board = [
  [{pieceName: "blackCastle"}, {pieceName: "blackHorse"}, {pieceName: "blackBishop"}, {pieceName: "blackQueen"}, {pieceName: "blackKing"}, {pieceName: "blackBishop"}, {pieceName: "blackHorse"}, {pieceName: "blackCastle"}],
  [{pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}, {pieceName: "blackPawn"}],
  ["vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant"],
  ["vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant"],
  ["vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant"],
  ["vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant", "vacant"],
  [{pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}, {pieceName: "whitePawn"}],
  [{pieceName: "whiteCastle"}, {pieceName: "whiteHorse"}, {pieceName: "whiteBishop"}, {pieceName: "whiteQueen"}, {pieceName: "whiteKing"}, {pieceName: "whiteBishop"}, {pieceName: "whiteHorse"}, {pieceName: "whiteCastle"}]
];

function pawnMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let moves = getEnpassantMoves(piecePosition, board);
  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);

  if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0){
    var isEnemyInTopLeft = !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName) && board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 1] != "vacant";
  }
  if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.x + 1 < 8){
    var isEnemyInTopRight = !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName) && board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 1] != "vacant";
  }
  if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0){
    var isEnemyInBottomLeft = !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName) && board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 1] != "vacant";
  }
  if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.x + 1 < 8){
    var isEnemyInBottomRight = !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName) && board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 1] != "vacant";
  }

function copyBoardArray(board){
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));
}

function reverse(array){
  return array.reverse();
}

const whitePieces = ["whitePawn", "whiteCastle", "whiteHorse", "whiteBishop", "whiteQueen", "whiteKing"];
const blackPieces = ["blackPawn", "blackCastle", "blackHorse", "blackBishop", "blackQueen", "blackKing"];

function isItemInArray(array, object){
  return (array.indexOf(object) == -1 ? false : true);
}

let whiteKingPieceSquareTable = [
  [-3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3],
  [-3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3],
  [-3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3],
  [-3, -4, -4, -5, -5, -4, -4, -3],
  [-2, -3, -3, -4, -4, -3, -3, -2],
  [-1, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -1],
  [2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2],
  [2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2]
];
let whiteQueenPieceSquareTable = [
  [-2, -1, -1, -0.5, -0.5, -1, -1, -2],
  [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
  [-1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, -1],
  [-0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, -0.5],
  [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, -0.5],
  [-1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, -1],
  [-1, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
  [-2, -1, -1, -0.5, -0.5, -1, -1, -2]
];
let whiteCastlePieceSquareTable = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5],
  [-0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5],
  [-0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5],
  [-0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5],
  [-0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5],
  [-0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5],
  [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0]
];
let whiteBishopPieceSquareTable = [
  [-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2],
  [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
  [-1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, -1],
  [-1, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, -1],
  [-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1],
  [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1],
  [-1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, -1],
  [-2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -2]
];
let whiteHorsePieceSquareTable = [
  [-5, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -5],
  [-4, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -4],
  [-3, 0, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 0, -3],
  [-3, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 0.5, -3],
  [-3, 0, 1.5, 2, 2, 1.5, 0, -3],
  [-3, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, -3],
  [-4, -2, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, -2, -4],
  [-5, -4, -3, -3, -3, -3, -4, -5],
];
let whitePawnPieceSquareTable = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1],
  [0.5, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5],
  [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
  [0.5, -0.5, -1, 0, 0, -1, -0.5, 0.5],
  [0.5, 1, 1, -2, -2, 1, 1, 0.5],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
let blackKingPieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whiteKingPieceSquareTable));
let blackQueenPieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whiteQueenPieceSquareTable));
let blackCastlePieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whiteCastlePieceSquareTable));
let blackBishopPieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whiteBishopPieceSquareTable));
let blackHorsePieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whiteBishopPieceSquareTable));
let blackPawnPieceSquareTable = reverse(getNegativePieceSquareTable(whitePawnPieceSquareTable));



  let boardPosition = board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x];
  let isPieceInBackOfBoard = piecePosition.y == 6;
  let isPieceInTopOfBoard = piecePosition.y == 1;
  humanPlayer == whitePieces ? pawnInBottom = "whitePawn" : pawnInBottom = "blackPawn";
  if(boardPosition.pieceName == pawnInBottom){
    if(isPieceInBackOfBoard){
      if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
      }
      if(board[piecePosition.y - 2][piecePosition.x] == "vacant" && board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 2}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 2}});
      }
    } else if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0){
      if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
      }
    }
    if(isEnemyInTopLeft){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
    if(isEnemyInTopRight){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  } else {
    if(isPieceInTopOfBoard){
      if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
      }
      if(board[piecePosition.y + 2][piecePosition.x] == "vacant" && board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 2}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 2}});
      }
    } else if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8){
      if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant"){
        moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
      }
    }
    if(isEnemyInBottomLeft){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
    if(isEnemyInBottomRight){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}), hasPawnMoved: true, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}})
    }
  }

  return moves;
}

function castleMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let moves = [];
  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);

  for(i = piecePosition.x + 1; i < 8; i++){
    if(board[piecePosition.y][i] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][i].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[piecePosition.y][i] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][i].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}});
  }

  for(i = piecePosition.x - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(board[piecePosition.y][i] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][i].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[piecePosition.y][i] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][i].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: i, y: piecePosition.y}});
  }

  for(i = piecePosition.y + 1; i < 8; i++){
    if(board[i][piecePosition.x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[i][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[i][piecePosition.x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[i][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}});
  }

  for(i = piecePosition.y - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(board[i][piecePosition.x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[i][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[i][piecePosition.x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[i][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: true}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}), hasPawnMoved: false, hasPieceBeenCaptured: false}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: i}});
  }

  return moves; 
}

function update(board, from, to){  
  let boardCopy = copyBoardArray(board);
  boardCopy = setEnpassantTargetSquares(boardCopy, from, to);
  let piece = boardCopy[from.y][from.x];
  boardCopy[from.y][from.x] = "vacant";
  boardCopy[to.y][to.x] = piece;
  boardCopy[to.y][to.x].hasClicked = true;
  return boardCopy;
}

function returnCastledBoard(kingPos, to, board){
  boardDeepClone = copyBoardArray(board);
  let king = boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x];
  if(to.x > kingPos.x){
    castlingCastle = boardDeepClone[to.y][7];
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x] = "vacant";
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x + 2] = king;
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x + 2].hasClicked = true;
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][7] = "vacant";
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x + 1] = castlingCastle;
  } else {
    castlingCastle = boardDeepClone[to.y][7];
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x] = "vacant";
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x - 2] = king;
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x - 2].hasClicked = true;
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][0] = "vacant";
    boardDeepClone[kingPos.y][kingPos.x - 1] = castlingCastle;
  }
  return boardDeepClone;
}

function returnEnpassantBoard(board, target, from, to){
  let boardCopy = copyBoardArray(board);
  boardCopy[target.y][target.x] = "vacant";
  boardCopy = update(boardCopy, from, to);
  return boardCopy;
}

function castlingMoves(pieceType, board){
  let castlingMoves = [];
  pieceType == blackPieces ? king = "blackKing" : king = "whiteKing";
  let kingPos = getPiecePosition(king, board);
  let isPieceBlocking;
  let playerInCheck;
  if(board[kingPos.y][kingPos.x].hasClicked === undefined){
    if(board[kingPos.y][0].hasClicked === undefined &&
      (board[kingPos.y][0].pieceName == "blackCastle" || board[kingPos.y][0].pieceName == "whiteCastle")
    ){
      for(xPos = kingPos.x - 1; xPos >= 1; xPos--){
        if(board[kingPos.y][xPos] == "vacant"){
          isPieceBlocking = false;
        } else if(board[kingPos.y][xPos] != "vacant"){
          isPieceBlocking = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!isPieceBlocking){
        for(xPos = kingPos.x; xPos >= kingPos.x - 2; xPos--){
          bCopy = copyBoardArray(board);
          bCopy = update(board, kingPos, {x: xPos, y: kingPos.y});
          if(isPlayerInCheck(pieceType, bCopy)){
            playerInCheck = true;
            break;
          } else {
            playerInCheck = false;
          }
        }
      }
      if(!isPieceBlocking && !playerInCheck){
        castlingMoves.push({node: {
          board: returnCastledBoard(kingPos, {x: kingPos.x - 2, y: kingPos.y}, board)},
          to: {x: kingPos.x - 2, y: kingPos.y}
        });
      }
    }
    if(board[kingPos.y][7].hasClicked === undefined && 
      (board[kingPos.y][7].pieceName == "blackCastle" || board[kingPos.y][7].pieceName == "whiteCastle")
    ){
      for(xPos = kingPos.x + 1; xPos <= 6; xPos++){
        if(board[kingPos.y][xPos] == "vacant"){
          isPieceBlocking = false;
        } else if(board[kingPos.y][xPos] != "vacant"){
          isPieceBlocking = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(!isPieceBlocking){
        for(xPos = kingPos.x; xPos <= kingPos.x + 2; xPos++){
          bCopy = copyBoardArray(board);
          bCopy = update(board, kingPos, {x: xPos, y: kingPos.y});
          if(isPlayerInCheck(pieceType, bCopy)){
            playerInCheck = true;
            break;
          } else {
            playerInCheck = false;
          }
        }
      }
      if(!isPieceBlocking && !playerInCheck){
        castlingMoves.push({node: {
          board: returnCastledBoard(kingPos, {x: kingPos.x + 2, y: kingPos.y}, board)},
          to: {x: kingPos.x + 2, y: kingPos.y}
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return castlingMoves;
}

function bishopMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let moves = [];
  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);

  x = piecePosition.x + 1;
  y = piecePosition.y + 1;

  while(x < 8 && y < 8){
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
    x += 1;
    y += 1;
  }

  x = piecePosition.x - 1;
  y = piecePosition.y - 1;

  while(x >= 0 && y >= 0){
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
    x -= 1;
    y -= 1;
  }

  x = piecePosition.x - 1;
  y = piecePosition.y + 1;

  while(x >= 0 && y < 8){
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
    x -= 1;
    y += 1;
  }

  x = piecePosition.x + 1;
  y = piecePosition.y - 1;

  while(x < 8 && y >= 0){
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      break;
    }
    if(board[y][x] != "vacant" && !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[y][x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
      break;
    }
    moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: x, y: y})}, to: {x: x, y: y}});
    x += 1;
    y -= 1;
  }

  return moves; 
}

function horseMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let moves = [];
  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);

  if(piecePosition.x + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.y + 2 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 2][piecePosition.x + 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 2][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 2})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 2}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.y + 2 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 2][piecePosition.x - 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 2][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 2})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 2}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.y - 2 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 2][piecePosition.x + 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 2][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 2})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 2}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.y - 2 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 2][piecePosition.x - 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 2][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 2})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 2}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x + 2 < 8 && piecePosition.y + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 2] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 2].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 2, y: piecePosition.y + 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 2, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x - 2 >= 0 && piecePosition.y + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 2] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 2].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 2, y: piecePosition.y + 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 2, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x + 2 < 8 && piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 2] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 2].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 2, y: piecePosition.y - 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 2, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x - 2 >= 0 && piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 2] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 2].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 2, y: piecePosition.y - 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 2, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  }

  return moves;
}

function kingMoves(piecePosition, board){
  moves = [];

  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);

  if(piecePosition.x + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x + 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x - 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.x + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y + 1 < 8 && piecePosition.x - 1 >= 0){
    if(board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y + 1][piecePosition.x - 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x - 1, y: piecePosition.y + 1}});
    }
  }

  if(piecePosition.y - 1 >= 0 && piecePosition.x + 1 < 8){
    if(board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 1] == "vacant" || !isItemInArray(pieceType, board[piecePosition.y - 1][piecePosition.x + 1].pieceName)){
      moves.push({node: {board: update(board, piecePosition, {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1})}, to: {x: piecePosition.x + 1, y: piecePosition.y - 1}});
    }
  }

  return moves;
}

function queenMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let castleMovesForQueen = castleMoves(piecePosition, board);
  let bishopMovesForQueen = bishopMoves(piecePosition, board);
  let moves = castleMovesForQueen.concat(bishopMovesForQueen);
  return moves;
}

function getValidMoves(piecePosition, board){
  let boardPos = board[piecePosition.y][piecePosition.x]
  let pieceType = getPieceType(piecePosition, board);
  let unfilteredMoveSet;

  if(castlingMoves(pieceType, board).length != 0 && (boardPos.pieceName == "whiteKing" || boardPos.pieceName == "blackKing")){
    unfilteredMoveSet = castlingMoves(pieceType, board);
    let unfilteredMoveSetAddon = getUncheckedMoves(piecePosition, board).move;
    unfilteredMoveSet = unfilteredMoveSet.concat(unfilteredMoveSetAddon);
  } else {
    unfilteredMoveSet = getUncheckedMoves(piecePosition, board).move;
  }

  for(index = unfilteredMoveSet.length - 1; index >= 0; index--){
    if(isPlayerInCheck(pieceType, unfilteredMoveSet[index].node.board)){
      unfilteredMoveSet.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  return {from: piecePosition, move: unfilteredMoveSet};
}

function isCheckmate(pieceType, board){
  let validSpots = availableValidSpots(board, pieceType);
  if(validSpots.length == 0 && isPlayerInCheck(pieceType, board)){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function isPlayerInCheck(player, board){
  setPlayerInfo(player, board);

  for(opponentMove = 0; opponentMove < opponentMoves.length; opponentMove++){
    for(square = 0; square < opponentMoves[opponentMove].move.length; square++){
      if(opponentMoves[opponentMove].move[square].to.x == kingPosition.x && opponentMoves[opponentMove].move[square].to.y == kingPosition.y){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function findBestMove(board, player){
  player == blackPieces ? isMaximisingPlayer = false : isMaximisingPlayer = true;
  let availSpots = availableValidSpots(board, player);
  if(isMaximisingPlayer){
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    for(availSpot = 0; availSpot < availSpots.length; availSpot++){
      let value = alphaBeta(availSpots[availSpot].node, 2, -Infinity, Infinity, true);
      if(value > bestScore){
        bestScore = value;
        bestMove = availSpots[availSpot];
      }
    }
  } else {
    let bestScore = Infinity;
    for(availSpot = 0; availSpot < availSpots.length; availSpot++){
      let value = alphaBeta(availSpots[availSpot].node, 2, -Infinity, Infinity, false);
      if(value < bestScore){
        bestScore = value;
        bestMove = availSpots[availSpot];
      }
    }
  }
  return bestMove;
}

function isTerminalNode(node){
  return isCheckmate(blackPieces, node) || isCheckmate(whitePieces, node);
}

function alphaBeta(node, depth, alpha, beta, isMaximisingPlayer){
  if(depth == 0 || isTerminalNode(node)){
    return evaluateBoard(node);
  }
  isMaximisingPlayer ? player = whitePieces : player = blackPieces;
  let availableSpots = availableValidSpots(node, player);
  if(isMaximisingPlayer){
    value = -Infinity;
    for(availableSpot = 0; availableSpot < availableSpots.length; availableSpot++){
      let child = availableSpots[availableSpot].node;
      value = Math.max(value, alphaBeta(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false));
      alpha = Math.max(alpha, value);
      if(beta <= alpha){
        //console.log("BREAK");
        break;
      }
    }
    return value;
  } else {
    value = Infinity;
    for(availableSpot = 0; availableSpot < availableSpots.length; availableSpots++){
      let child = availableSpots[availableSpot].node;
      value = Math.min(value, alphaBeta(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true));
      beta = Math.min(beta, value);
      if(beta <= alpha){
        //console.log("BREAK");
        break;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data so we can have [mcve] of the behaviour?

Comment: @VLAZ By "Sample Data" do you mean information about the time that the functions shown in the code took to execute?

Comment: Yes, something that we can run the function with to get reproducible output. Feel free to make the sample really small as long as we can run `findBestMove(someSampleBoard, someSamplePlayer)` and can see the problem, it should be OK.

Comment: @VLAZ All the code and move generation required to run the engine exceeds the 30,000 character limit, how could I post a runnable engine?

Comment: Why do you have one findBestMove function and one alphaBeta function?

Comment: @eligolf findBestMove is to find the best branch to go to based on evaluation by alpha beta, I tried doing it on alpha beta but it returned the move which will be played a few moves from now.

Comment: So now you are doing the recursive function twice? Instead you could save the best move AND the evaluation in your alphaBeta directly and return both values. I think that would save tons of time to begin with.

Comment: @eligolf how might I do that?

Comment: @SwatiRawatChandra See the posted answer since I can't seem to post code in the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are doing the recursive calls twice, once for getting the score and once for the move. Remove the findBestMove function and in your alphaBeta you write something like this (pseudo code):

```
function minimax(board, .....):
    availableMoves = getAvailableMoves(board, player)

    if depth == 0 or isCheckMate or isDraw:
        return None, evaluation(board)

    if maxPlayer:
        bestValue = -inf
        for move in availableMoves:
            boardCopy = deepcopy(board)
            boardCopy.move(move)
            value = minimax(boardCopy, ....)[1]

            if value > bestValue:
                bestValue = value
                bestMove = move

        return bestMove, bestValue

    else:
        .......
```